# java incompatible type T cannot converted to Enum

Tags: java, generics

The code is running fine in eclipse but giving following error while trying to compile in intellij IDEA

```
public class Sample{
   private Map<Class<Enum>, IConverter<? extends Enum<?>>> enumConverter = Maps.newHashMap();


public <T extends Enum<T>> T  getEnumAttribute(String key, final Class<T> ee){
    IConverter<T> e = (IConverter<T>)enumConverters.get(ee);
    if ( e == null ){
        e = new IConverter<T>() {
            @Override
            public String toString(T val) {
                return val.toString();
            }

            @Override
            public Class<T> getType() {
                return ee;
            }

            @Override
            public T fromString(String val) {
                return Enum.valueOf(ee, val);
            }
        };
        enumConverters.put((Class<Enum>) ee, e);
    }
    return getAttribute(key, e);
}

public static interface IConverter<T> extends Serializable{
    public  T fromString(String val);
    public String toString(T val);
    public Class<T> getType();
}     


}
```

The code is compiling fine in eclipse but throwing an error in

`enumConverters.put((Class<Enum>) ee, e);` line as

`Error:(521, 66) java: incompatible types: java.lang.Class<T> cannot be converted to java.lang.Class<java.lang.Enum>`

I am not sure what is wrong, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `Map<Class<Enum>IConverter<? extends Enum<?>>>` What is that ? That compiles fine?

Comment: Yes, sorry, it is very old code

Comment: I doubt that this compiles at all, no matter how old that is.

Comment: change `Map<Class<Enum>, IConverter<? extends Enum<?>>>` to `Map<Class<? extends Enum<?>>, IConverter<? extends Enum<?>>>` and you'll be fine

Comment: A `Class<T extends Enum<T>>` isn't a `Class<Enum>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `Class<T extends Enum<T>>` isn't a `Class<Enum>`, just as a `Class<String>` isn't a `Class<Object>`, or `List<T>` isn't a `List<Object>`.

Change your map declaration to:

```
private Map<Class<? extends Enum<?>>, IConverter<? extends Enum<?>>> enumConverter = Maps.newHashMap();
```